# Robust way to event handle after the *last* CSS3 transition?

Tags: javascript, css, event-handling, css-transitions

Say I have a CSS class that transitions in several settings, with different timings to boot:

```
.hidden {
  opacity:0;
  height:0px;
  transition:opacity 1s ease;
  transition:height 2s ease;
}
```

I want to handle some logic after ALL the transitions are done. I know there's a transitionend event for that:

```
$('#content').on('transitionend', function(e) {
  mandatoryLogic()
})

$('#content').addClass('hidden');
```

But, how do I ensure this event handle happens once and only once, at the end of the last transition (after the 2s height transition in my case)?

I've seen a few examples that involve checking for the type of transitionend, but this closely couples the JS to a particular CSS definition. So far I'm unable to come up with a JS solution that would survive say:

- opacity changed to 3s, now the longest.
- new width transition to 0px over 4s introduced
- extreme case, all transitions removed (so the effects are instant)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but if you want to make sure it only happens once, then use a variable set to `false` initially, and once the transition takes place it gets set to `true`. For example:

```
var transition = false ;
if( !transition ){
    // do what you need to do
    transition = true ;
}
```

If you want to make sure it happens once all transitions are complete, then check for the values of `#content` or `.hidden`. Whichever you prefer.

```
var height = $(element).height() ;
var opacity = $(element).css('opacity') ;
var transition = false ;
if( !transition && opacity = 'wanted value' && height = 'wanted value' ){
    // do what you need to do
    transition = true ;
}
```

This way, with `var transition` being set to true it won't happen again.

Comment: Your 2nd example is really the issue I'm trying to address - part of the idea of putting transitions into CSS is that we separate the styling from the logic. By adding checks for opacity and height into the JS, we've now tightly coupled them together.

Say my UX designer decides "we don't really need the height shrink just the opacity fade out is good enough". They change the css to just this:

    .hidden {
      opacity:0;
      transition:opacity 1s ease;
    }

All of a sudden your JS is broken and transition never gets triggered, because we have a hard-coded height check in there.

Comment: gah, no code in comments. The example shows the opacity transition removed, basically.